# Control several youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I'm looking for a way to control several iframe video on the same page with the same ID. I just want to mute them all but it only work for the first video. Here is my code ! Thanks !

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="200px"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bNkkFIjScY8?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="200px"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pKVvTKQgEH4?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady() {
            player.playVideo();
            // Mute!
            player.mute();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: The same value for `id` must not be used more than once!

Comment: Ok ! But I call the frame with a query and i don't know how to change the name of the different ID !